# What is the point of ActiveXObjects?

Tags: javascript, xml, activexobject

I have a task which requires me to create rows of tables using MSXML ActiveXObjects. I don't understand what an ActiveXObject has to do with anything. How could I create a table with that? Why wouldn't I just create the table in the HTML DOM?

I read various [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600419/xmlhttprequest-vs-activexobjectmicrosoft-xmlhttp-whats-the-point) and concluded that there seems to be a layer within the browser that is responsible for data transport of non-html related data. Is this essentially the point of ActiveXObjects?

This is essentially what I am trying to make: 
[image]
I just don't understand what roll the ActiveXObject plays here

Comment: Could you show what you're expected to do with `ActiveXObject`? That's a pretty general facility.

Comment: ActiveX is a generic technology for letting different Windows applications talk to each other through a standard API. We can't tell why your task would require its use.

Comment: MSXML is ONE ActiveX object but it's NOT THE ONLY ONE. I suppose (because you _have to_ use MSXML) that task is to populate that table asynchronously with AJAX. Is this only purpose of ActiveX objects? No, of course it's not. BTW MSXML is a XML parser, to handle XML (but not only) remote requests ("data transport") ActiveX object to use is XMLHTTP).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti — Ajax would be implied by XMLHttpRequest (and that doesn't use ActiveX in recent versions of IE), not MSXML.

Comment: @Quentin editing was in progress. I said "I suppose" because of that, even if XML file _may_ not come from AJAX I suspect it _was_ pretty common usage. BTW you're right about XMLHttpRequest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually pretty straight forward: the `ActiveXObject` is a Microsoft extension to JavaScript that provides you with an interface to Microsoft's software framework ActiveX. ActiveX basically is a set of modular software components which are used to build Microsoft's software products (which are in turn also available as ActiveX components, e.g. Excel).

[Wikiped Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX)

You can find some examples on the use of the `ActiveXObject` in the link below.

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7sw4ddf8%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

I can only guess what your task is, but if it involves at any point the use of a proprietary Microsoft specific software component, that would be the reason for using the `ActiveXObject`. Some functionalities provided by the `ActiveXObject` are however redundant (e.g. `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` since newer versions of Internet Explorer implement the standardized `XMLHttpRequest` interface).